# Provide ssl certificate from function node to http node

Tags: node-red

Hi I want provide ssl certificate path from the function node to http node how to do that ? like we can set url like msg.url="http://google.com" in function and send "msg" to http node

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do that.

The HTTP-Request node uses a config node to hold it's SSL/TLS certificate details, these can not be passed in as a message property.